# Compare Info from JSON, Return top results in list

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "group": "satellite-1",
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "feed1-1_TargetA",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:00 AM", "11:40:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:20 AM", "11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed1-1_TargetB",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:40 AM", "11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed1-1_TargetC",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:40 AM", "11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed1-1_TargetD",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:40 AM", "11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetD"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetD"},
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed1-2_TargetB",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:20 AM", "11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
                ]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "satellite-2",
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "feed2-1_TargetA",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:20 AM", "11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetA"},
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed2-1_TargetB",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:40 AM", "11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetB"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed2-1_TargetC",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:40 AM", "11:41:00 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                    {"timeRange": ["11:41:00 AM", "11:41:20 AM"], val: "TargetC"},
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "feed2-2_TargetB",
                "data": [
                    {"timeRange": ["11:40:20 AM", "11:40:40 AM"], val: "TargetB"}
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

I am attempting to compare which feeds saw the greatest # of Targets.

So far, I have this solved insomuch as I can loop through the JSON and return the "most observant feed" by comparing the length of each feed.

```
/*
 * Compare length of each sensor block in data to determine which sensor
 * is most observant
 */
var getMostObservantFeeds = function(entry){
    var bestFeed = null;


    for(var d of entry.data){
        if (bestFeed == null){
            bestFeed = d;
        }
        if (bestFeed.data.length < d.data.length){
            bestFeed = d;
        }
    }

    bestFeed = bestFeed || {};

    return bestFeed.label
    ])
};

var getMostObservantFeed = function(data_JSON){
    return data_JSON.map(x => getMostObservantFeeds(x));
};
```

HOWEVER, I cannot get this working for the case where a feed has the same length as another.

In the case where 2 feeds see the same number of targets (and that is the highest number seen) how do I return a list of the best feeds? (i.e. satellite2: feed2-1_TargetA, feed2-1_TargetB, feed2-1_TargetC)

Comment: Many implementations solve these ties using another value to sort on like alphabetic name or most recently updated. Would either of these options work?

Comment: I don't think so, I think I really need to key off the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about recording the maximum and comparing to that each time. And maybe just store the labels in an array since that's all you're returning?

```
var getMostObservantFeed = function(entry){
    var bestLabels = [];
    var max = 0;

    for(var d of entry.data){
        if (d.data.length >= max){
            max = d.data.length;
            bestLabels.push(d.label);
        }
    }

    return bestLabels;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use a second condition which checks if `bestFeed.data`and `d.data` have the same length. Add something like this after your second if-statement in the for-loop:

```
else if(bestFeed.data.length === d.data.length){  
    //do further checking here
}
```

Inside this condition, you can compare `bestfeed` and `d` again (maybe the `timerange` attribute).

I also recommend you to use something else than `d`, e.g `i` or `item`